# Potential risk of fire in attic insulation?

Tags: electrical, insulation

I was checking something in the attic today and noticed there are some black spots on the "paper/lining" side of the insulation (picture attached), obviously the black spots are the areas where the insulation "paper" side touching the bedroom ceiling light wiring that runs across the attic, I also noticed that the "inner" side of the insulation paper is black. When first seeing this I was very upset thinking that they are paper burns by the wire heat somehow, but after further look it feels like those black spots are more of black stains instead of paper burns, because if I scratch them with my nails they don't fall off, but I am still not sure... Has anyone seen this before? Any idea if I should be worried about it?

Thank you!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What is that wire connected to?

Comment: Is that on a 15A or 20A breaker? While older Romex was white for various sizes, newer Romex (and from the labeling it looks relatively new) is white for 15A (14 AWG) and yellow for 20A (12 AWG). Also, the way it is run through the joist looks pretty nasty - splits in the side of the wood when it should have a clean hole.

Comment: @RibaldEddie manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact it is connecting to 6 ceiling lights (10w or 15w LED each I believe) in the bedroom. Since it is white I would guess it is 15A but I am not very sure.

Comment: @diabloooo0 if the rated load is not much then there could either be damage to the wire along the way or a malfunction in the lights.

Comment: 90W is basically "nothing". Are you sure the same circuit doesn't also feed some receptacles?

Comment: @EdBeal This just made me feel much better, lol... but just want to make sure I understand it right, so basically we are saying that this is NORMAL for insulations with tar on the paper side, correct? I just found another topic with similar problem and the answer says this: "That is tar from the old insulation, that's why it is sticky. I don't know why or how it happens, but old insulation had tar in the paper, and it is very common. It is not scorching or melting from overheating." https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/44807/what-are-these-marks-on-the-romex-wire-in-the-wall

Comment: @isherwood yup I did it myself for some of it yesterday by tugging the insulation under the wires, but there are more that not easy to access, I will just leave them as is. As long as it is not posting fire risk I am not too worried about it.

Comment: Just an update: I went ahead to turn on all the lights in the bedroom and fan in its bathroom, also turned on the small space heater, left it run for about half hour, then I went into the attic and checked the wire, I can't feel any warm sign on the wire using my finger, so it feels like the wires are safe..

Answer (score 0):

To amplify @Gil's answer, definitely overheated/overloaded wire.  Without more info it's impossible to say the cause, but certainly a huge cause of concern.  Can't tell whether it's current damage or from past electrical usage, but at some point that cable got hugely overheated.  I'd tend to dismiss the lightning theory, but I guess that could be possible.  More likely either that line is feeding a lot more than you think it is (such as a space heater, bathroom ceiling heater/fan combo, hair driers run for long periods of time), or there is a fault or partial short somewhere in your wiring that's drawing a lot of continuous current that's causing the line to heat up so much.  Could also be a bad or wrongly-sized circuit breaker allowing too much current to run.

In any case, I'd recommend bringing in a professional licensed electrician to troubleshoot your issue, and at a minimum replace any wiring that looks like that ASAP as the internal insulation is likely damaged and could be melted.

Comment: Sometime we do use space heater, and sometime we leave the bathroom fan runs long too... but that shouldn't on the same wire with the ceiling light? I mean the outlet line and the ceiling light line should be two different lines? I just checked the circuit breaker and it is 15A.

Comment: **Space heater!!!** Is it on the same circuit? As in, if you turn on the lights and plug in the space heater and turn it on, and then turn off the breaker that you think controls the lights, do *both* the lights and space heater turn off? Sometimes things are connected in twisty/crazy routes that you wouldn't expect.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact I just checked, seems they are not on the same circuit, when I turn off the breaker for the ceiling lights the space heater still runs. I also checked, it looks like the circuit in the picture covers the ceiling lights in the bed room and the lights in its adjacent bathroom, and the only long running thing would probably the bathroom fan..

Comment: Lights and bathroom exhaust fans are all low power items. A bathroom **heat fan** is another story, but most people don't have that. So that still leaves open the mystery of how/when/why the wire overheated.

Comment: I am very confused too, and neither I ever smell burning smell in the room. Are we 100% sure that is burn? Because when I try to scratch those black spots with my nail and they don't fall off like burned paper normally do..is it possible that the black paint on the insulation lining/paper penetrated through onto the wire due to moderate within-normal-range heat?

Comment: In light of wisdom shared in comments and the duplicate question, this answer doesn't seem to be correct.

Answer (score -1):

The Owens insulation indicates it is overheated and was at the kindling point.  The fact that the outer shell of the wire is as intact as it is is a little confusing but could also indicate lightning damage. I am basing this on your picture that shows the wire surface is indented as it would do if overheated.  Are you the original owner and do you know of any work that was done on the house in this area. One way to check is place some non flammable fiberglass insulation over the wire after attaching a temperature sensor to it. If it gets more then a few degrees warmer it is overloaded and needs replacement and a wire size validation. What is connected to it. A inexpensive Indoor/Outdoor thermometer that records the max high would work. Before doing this you need to check to be sure the breaker is OK, changing it would be a good idea. Be sure the breaker is appropriate for wire size. My recommendation is to replace both the wire and breaker with the appropriate size. While you are at it check other wires to see if they show the same thing, if so you need professional help who will megger your home as it is most likely lightning damage.

Comment: Looks like my 1st step is to get a temperature sensor, do you think something like this will work? https://www.amazon.com/MEGGSI-Hygrometer-Thermometer-Probe-Temperature/dp/B09243DTBH/ref=sr_1_10?crid=2S3KDRJ9DADAP&keywords=temperature+sensor+wire+electrnic&qid=1640204457&sprefix=temperature+sensor+wire+electrnic%2Caps%2C71&sr=8-10.

Comment: In light of wisdom shared in comments and the duplicate question, this answer doesn't seem to be correct.